# Непонятные отступы при увеличении размера шрифта

Tags: css

При увеличении размера шрифта Raleway, у текста начинает появлятся непонятный отступ сверху. Как его убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
.test {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 126px;
}
```

Comment: это стандартные отступы и они есть у любого шрифта что бы избавится от них то обнуляйте либо  line-height либо margin у тега `<p></p>` или что бы там применяете

Comment: https://css-live.ru/css/metriki-shrifta-line-height-vertical-align.html

здесь подробно объясняется, откуда это все берется.

Answer (score 3):

Укажите параметр css line-height
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

```
.test {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size: 126px;
line-height: 100px;
}
```

> В примере указано произвольное значение